# How to get the index of list value and value too choosen by user input

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling

I want that a user can enter digits and if the digits matches with the list values then the program returns the entered value and it's index too.

How can i do that? 
I have written some line of code but it is not working....

```
a = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]

inp = int(input("Enter digit"))
i =0
for i in a:
    if inp == a[i]:
        print("You found it {}".format(a[i]))
else:
        print("No found")
```

It is raising an IndexError.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for i in a` iterates over the *elements* of `a`, not over its integer indices.

You can fix your code by using `enumerate`.

```
a = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]
inp = int(input('Enter digit: '))

for index, value in enumerate(a):
    if value == inp:
        print('You found it at position {}'.format(index))
        break
else: # no break
    print('not found')
```

Additionally, I changed the *string* `input('Enter digit: ')` returns to an `int` and `break` out of the loop once the target has been seen once.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176918/finding-the-index-of-an-item-given-a-list-containing-it-in-python) for solutions how to program this behavior outside of a programming exercise (TL;DR: `a.index(inp)`).

Comment: Yes this is giving 'You found it' String but i want the index of entered value. I edited with print('You found it {}'.format(value)) but it is giving the value not index

Comment: @ArvinaKori ok, I covered that now.

Comment: Pythonic solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
for i in a:
   if inp == a[i]:
       ...
```

to

```
for i in a:
   if inp == i:
       ...
```

Because `for` loop iterate over elements in list.(not over index)

Comment: It is performing the else block & giving a loop of "No Found" string.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use

```
for i in range(len(a)):
```

The index error is raised by the fact that you construct your `for` loop as `for i in a`, which means that `i` will iterate through the contents of `a`. Then calling `a[i]` will not work because in the first step of the loop you are calling `a[10]`.

Alternatively, you could step through the elements of `a` directly like this:

```
for a_element in a:
    if inp == a_element:
```

Which will compare the user input to the contents of `a`.

Comment: I think it would be useful if you elaborated a bit. Where should this line be used? Why didn't the code in the question work?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a for loop is necessary:

```
l = [i for i in range(0,100,10)]

def found_it():
    print("You found it {}".format(l.index(ans)))
    if ans in l:
        print("You found it")
    else:
        print("Try again")
        found_it()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]

inp = int(input("Enter digit: "))

if inp in a:
    print("You found {} at {}".format(inp, a.index(inp)))
else:
    print("Not found")
```

Answer (score 0):

More pythonic way would be:

```
a = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]

inp = int(input("Enter digit :"))
if inp in a:
  print "You found", inp, "at index:", a.index(inp)
else:
  print "Not found"
```

Output:

```
Enter digit :10
You found 10 at index: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly,always convert the user input into an integer using the int() function, before finding it in the list of integers.

I guess you only need to find whether one element is there in list or not.For that you can try this:

```
a = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]

inp = int(input("Enter digit"))
if inp in a:
    print("You found it at index {}".format(a.index(inp)))
else:
    print("Not found")
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some logical mistakes in the code :

1. The input function return the string value & you are comparing the
   string value 'inp' with the array int value. Need to type-cast the
   value.
2. for i in a (means you are accessing each value of array 'a' in the
       variable 'i'). Here 'i' is not use as a index variable. Need to
       update it with 'for i in range(0,len(a))' (which means iterate the
       for-loop till the length of array 'a' with the index value of 'i').

**Code :**

```
a = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]
flag = 0 
inp = int(input("Enter digit"))
for i in range(0,len(a)):
    if inp == a[i]:
        print("You found it")
        print("index = ", i)
        flag = 1
        break
if flag == 0:
    print("No found")
```

**Output :**

[image]

Comment: On point 3: `for`/`else` is a valid Python construct. The `else` block is executed at most once, if and only if the `for` loop runs to completion without ever `break`ing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `in` to check it in the list

```
lst = [11, 1, 4, 15, 6]
userInput = int(input('Enter Value')) # IF IT IS INT
if userInput in lst:
    print(userInput, lst.index(userInput))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are facing this problem because in for loop i get the array values and storing in i that's why showing Index Error.

Here us the code to find Input no and matching no:

```
a=[10,20,30,40,50,60]

inp=20

i=0

for i in a:

    c = i 

    print(c)

    if inp==i:

        print("You found it")
```

Code Output:

```
10
20
You found it
30
40
50
60
```

Answer (score 0):

no need to use for loop to search for one type of num,
You can use a "Conditional Statement".

[image: search algorithm using if statement]

```py
a = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]

inp = int(input("Enter digit"))
if inp in a:
    index = a.index(inp)
    print(f"You found it, {inp} located in list on index {index}")
else:
    print("Not found")
```

Comment: Sure there is no explicit for loop, but this is two times less efficient as `in` must read the list a first time, and `a.index` a second time.